# Forming "complete" keys for google datastore v1 Entity using Java API

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing a collection of Entities (ie PCollection< Entity >) into the datastore from within a dataflow job. I am using Java, Apache Beam SDK and Datastore V1 APIs. I write it in the following way :
`entities.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId("my-project-id"));`

where entities is a PCollection of type Entity

For dataflow jobs, each Entity must have a "complete key". What is the best way to allocate Ids within a dataflow job ? I need "numeric" keys for the entities, and as of now , I have a hacky way of doing it, which I am not comfortable with

```
Key.Builder keyBuilder = DatastoreHelper.makeKey("StudentRecord", UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits());
```

Could someone suggest a better way to do it ? I am not familiar with the Datastore V1 APIs , and not sure how exactly to perform the RPC call which the documentation here prescribes

[AllocateIds](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/rpc/google.datastore.v1#google.datastore.v1.AllocateIdsRequest)

If someone could provide me some sample code, it would help immensely. Thanks !

Comment: Did you manage to do this ?

Comment: Nope. I finally resorted to using a string for the ID, and created UUIDs .